# MS ACCESS: Form and subform to fully link? or Form and unbound continous subform?

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, unbound, continuous-forms

I am trying to design a Purchase Order form called "Master PO", that contains a continuous subform called POContent. For this, I am using 2 tables called tblMasterPO and tblPOsContent. Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Screenshot]

The key points are that the Master PO form is a split view with a datasheet view on the top, and a combination of text and combo boxes at the bottom. The "PO Content" subform is a continuous form in the lower part of the Master PO form.

At my company, we are trying to keep record of every change we do to a Purchase Order for future analysis, hence the need of a PO revision number. The idea is every time we make a change to the Master PO or PO Content, I will create a new record with the updated data when the user will click on the "save/update PO" button, using (a lot of) VBA code. The Form / Sub-form combination is not really the best way of calling it, as it should actually be 2 fully linked table in a way (if PO content changes, then Master PO will be updated as well with a new ID#).

I have multiple questions to reach this goal of making this Form work:

- What would be the best way/practice to make sure that I can switch to form and subform fields freely? By, for example, dirtying both tables at the same time? Or have an unbound continuous subform? or a Temporary table?
- If I use the unbound continuous subform, how can I have the user add lines when adding a new item to the PO? For example, I would like the user to click on the datasheet form to view a PO, which would then populate the PO content items in the unbound subform. But when the user click on "New PO" button, he would then have no data in any of the Master PO AND PO Content fields, so user could then add items in the form and subform, and finally save everything by clicking on the "Save/Update PO" button.

**Do you have any tips or ideas to make this work on access?**

I know there will be a lot of VBA, but I am expecting it; I am just trying to find workarounds/solutions from experienced access programmers!

Thank you!

***EDIT 1:***

Basically, when creating a PO, the workflow is to first add general information such as, who is creating the PO, what date, what project is it related to etc; These go to the "master PO" table. Then, you want to actually add items to this PO, so you have multiple lines (for example you want 1x pack of screws, then 2x packs of nuts etc). When you are done doing the PO, you can finally save it using the "Save/Update PO" button, that will save everything in the dedicated tables.

Parent form is indeed automatically updated if I start adding items to the subform, but this is what I am trying to "pause", while I add parts in the subform. The "easiest" would probably be to have one table combining both, but the database will grow extremely fast if I have to save the same general information for each "PO content" line (meaning every time I add an item to the purchase order, I will save the vendor, the username, the date ordered...); I would have something like 100+ columns in my table for each item I order, for each revision, for each PO!

Set a flag or Public variable is something I looked into, but I am not sure how I could stop the entry of the main form while I am adding items into the subform.

Dirtying the parent file is also something I thought about; but it means that we will have 2 instances of the "general data" when creating a PO, because you will first add items into the master PO fields, then move onto the PO content subform that will automatically save the Master PO data under an ID#. And then, when actually adding items to the subform, it will them redirty the parent form, creating another ID# for the same data;

Can we combine both entry at the same time? Some kind of 2 table full link because one does not exist without the other?

Answer (score 1):

I not sure much VBA is required.
The save of the parent table (parent form) is automatic in Access. the instant you change focus to sub form, the parent form record is saved (and it REALLY is good it works this way).

As for a change/mod in the sub form, and you need to update the parents form PO number?

Well, the before change event in the sub form does not fire unless you made changes to that one row. So you can go:

```
me.Parent.form!PONum = "some new number".
```

But, it not clear if you only want ONE change for multiple change(s) in the sub form, or you want to do this for "many" changes in one given go?

I betting that this new PO update is to only occur once, even if you change several sub-form rows. So, that can be a challenge. In that case, I would probably set a form level flag in the sub form (Public var - start of the code module. Thus once any before change event fires, it can set this flag that one, or many records have been changed. Thus, at this point, then we need a "point" in time in which we update the parent form as a result of the one, or several rows having been changed. Note that the parent form can look at, get/grab/test/see if that "flag" in the sub form shows changes. So, then the question is how does the user "act" when they are done? Since they might decide that a few more changes are required in that sub form - and do some more editing. But, as noted, that just means our sub form changed flag we have will STILL show true.

So, the key issue then becomes at what point in time and how we decide they are done? Once we determine this (maybe closing the form???), then we have a point in time at which we know the sub form rows (1, or many) have been changed. And thus we need to check this changed flag in the main form when we leave that record, or say close the form.

What I would do in this case is actually make sure the sub for editing causes the main record to become dirty. That way no matter HOW the user leaves this current main record, the before change event will fire, and at that point in time you can check if the sub form had changes (with that flag). And thus at at point in time is when you can update the new PO number, and copy out the record to the change history. (which should only be a few lines of VBA - 2-3 inserts perhaps?

Edit:
Ok, one of the pressing issues of course is how to complete the whole thing, but not necessary save it. Well, with bound forms, we save HUGE amounts of code. But then how do we deal with something that may not be finished, not necessary done, and perhaps requires more edits, and THEN we are done?

Well, no question the end user does NOT care about relational database theory, and when they see a form, they just think of "save". But that's not how access works WHEN we introduce related data (such as sub forms).
However, we don't have the ability to wrap the main form (table) and the child form (table(s)) in a single transaction concept. You can do this in other systems, but then again, they are using dis-connected recordsets, and don't enjoy the HUGE savings in wriring up the code for editing like we do in Access.

So, for example, I had a system for colleciton of donations. The problem of couse is that during data entry, you would have to enter all of the donattions. And like a classic quickbooks screen, you would enter say $100, but THEN have to split that amount into multiple accounts. And I don't allow saving of the data nless the split amounts match the main reocrd donation amount. But, since we don't ahve that "save" that is the result of the form + sub form?

Well, I introduced what they did in the old days! - (batch processing). So, I allow the user to enter many dontaitons for a event. And they can do the split out of the accounts for each amount. They can edit, can add, can change their mind - go away, go for cofee, and come back and edit some more. But I added a POST job button. So, after they enter the data, 1 donation, maybe 20, when they hit post to finish their work, I THEN check if the split amounts match the donati0n amounts. If they do not, then I don't allow them to post. but, the post is not some big computer run of posting data. It simiply a field in the main post run. So you can't post unless the amounts match. And once they have posted, then I don't allow them to edit or change that data. The screen looks like this:

[image]

So, on the top? That is the event (date, time, addtional infomaton). And it also has the batch run, and psoting status. On the left side is the person + donation amount, and on the right side is the split of that given amount. (and the total box goes green if the amounts split out match the donation amount. But I STILL allow them to continue working - even if the amounts don't match. But untill that posting flag is set? Then I don't include that data in the reports and system. So, the posting does not move reocrds or anything - but I only chnage the one batch flag that the all the reocrds belong to. and I included that posted flag in the quiers that pull that data - if not post flag, then that rocord is not considerd valid untill such time the batch run is posted! And once posted, then they can't edit that data.

In your case, you thus could have a edit button. You dont' allow any editing of the form + sub form untill they hit edit. Once they do, you flip allow edits = true, and then they can freely edit main + sub form. But only have they had the button "done" editing (which could be the same button as edit - you hide one show the other). that way, you have a work cycle in which they start editing, and have to hit done editing. when done. You could even prompt when they leave or close the form to post or not.

Comment: Thank you Albert! Your help is greatly appreciated! I Edited my first post, you will see some more details under "EDIT 1:". I hope it will answer some of your questions and help you better see what I am trying to achieve; Some of your ideas might probably be the right ones!

Comment: Some kind of flag is not at all a bad idea - see my additional comments. So, you could introduce a edit button. Until they hit that button, you don't allow editing on that po.

Comment: I see; But how would the edit button work for both forms? I mean, let's say I create this button and put the vba code that switch the allow edit on/off of the Master PO form, I would still not be able to jump from Master PO Form to PO Content subform without saving the Master PO Form, right? I guess, if I do not allow edit, the text and combo boxes will be like "locked", but it does not mean I would be able to switch from one another if I allow edit... What was behind your donation code? Was there a temporary table? That would then be saved into the real tables if amount were the same?

Comment: You disable the sub form control - then the sub forms is locked. And you can always set the sub form to not allow edits. And no temps tables in that posted access form example (kind of the whole point). You can freely enter data but when you are done and do hit post? If the numbers don't match and add up - then you not allowed to close the posting run. But that post button does not actually post anything (looks like it does). It simply sets a posted flag in the top most form (there are 3 forms in that example top, left and right). If top form post flag set then not further edits are allowed.

Comment: While your use case is different, the concept of the "thing" in question still being open to edits or changes still applies.  Once its posted, then no further edits are allowed.  It was done this way since I did not have the ability to wrap the whole form + sub forms in a single save button - so I did not! and took a different road.   If access could edit the whole forms  + several forms as one save button concept, then I would not have to do the above. But it works well in most workflows - you simply introduce this concept of posting the given work, and it is still either open or closed.

Comment: You don't have to call it posting. You could call it open, and then closed. You open the thing for work, and then when done, you have to close it and then you set the flag in the main record that reflects this. And if they want to work more, then they have to open the job again - and you start the process over again. And in fact having to close the work job means you have a great work flow in which you can then write out and save that job/thing/invoice/widget or whatever the heck that process represents. So one has the concept of that given thing being open, or closed.

Comment: Hi Albert, I have been reading and re-reading and I think I now understand! I felt really dumb but I now understand your point! Basically, the subform would only be unlocked when the PO is first created (using some VBA), when the user is ok with it, and click on save, the subform will lock so user cannot modify it; but if user wants to modify it again, it could click on your toggle button, which would create a new revision (in the background) and unlock the subform again!
Got it, very smart and seem possible now that I understand it! I will try this and let you know! Cheers

Comment: yes - that's the idea. The problem is we don't have a islotaed save that means form + sub form. So, we kind of introduction our own layer or approach. So call it open, or close, or un-lock or whatever. But once closed, they can't edit. And if they want to edit, then they are starting a new process all over again. This allows you to quite much go with standard form + main form editing, but you have to open, and then close out that editing process. And when closed, they can't edit - only view until they hit open. And while it is open - no problem - they can even come back to work later on it.

Comment: This makes sense now; the close / un-lock was throwing me off, I wasn't getting it! Very smart solution Albert! Thank you for your help! I will try to actually work on the solution and answer the question myself when I will have something that is functioning (because this solution opens a bunch of other problems, but none of them are really scary at the moment, let's hope I can keep it that way ahah). Cheers